# Why am I getting a SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript

I am getting a SyntaxError: missing ; before statement. I have no idea why I'm getting this error since my code is EXACTLY the same as in the textbook I'm using. Please help. I will post code, and comment where syntax error is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Practive</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
input{display: block;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 250px;
text-align: left;}

label {float:left;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
fuction validateForm()                           // SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
    //  before v
{
if (document.forms[0].userAge.value < 18){
alert ("Age is less than 18!");
return false;
} // end if 
alert ("Age is valid.");
return true;
} // end function validateForm
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> JavaScript Form Handling </h1>
<form method="post" action="http://webdevfoundations.net/scripts/formdemo.asp" onsubmit="return             validateForm();"> 
<label for="userName">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
<label for="userAge">Age:   &nbsp </label>
<input type="text" name="userAge" id="userAge">
<input type="submit" value="send information" id="submit">
</form>     

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the code is EXACTLY as in the textbook, then the textbook is wrong

Answer (score 4):

Note this:

```
fuction validateForm()
```

should be:

```
function validateForm()
```

You forgot the N in word function and fixing that is solution to your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

write `function` instead of fuction in your script like this

```
function validateForm()                        
{
    if (document.forms[0].userAge.value < 18) {
        alert("Age is less than 18!");
        return false;
    } 
    alert("Age is valid.");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake in calling function

**Replace**

```
fuction validateForm()
```

**With**

```
function validateForm()
```

**You did spelling mistake in calling function.**